# libpcap capturing for a fixed amount of time & changing channel

Tags: c, libpcap

I would like to do the following in pseudo code:

```
   Setup interface 

loop:

   start capturing at current channel for 250msecs
   change channel using linux iwconfig
   goto loop:
```

How would i change below code to accompish this?

```
char error_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap_t *handle = pcap_create("wlan0", error_buffer);
pcap_set_rfmon(handler, 1);
pcap_set_timeout(handler, 250); /* Timeout in milliseconds */
pcap_activate(handle);
/* here i use pcap_loop() to capture the packets*/
```

Comment: Maybe use `for` or `while`?

Comment: To be clear , the code example above does not stop scanning after 250msecs. This is a timeout only and does not assure packetcapture takes max 250msecs

Comment: You could loop on 1 packet at a time until either count or timeout but the library doesn't provide a time limit.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13749514/1216776

Comment: If i understand correctly alarm() can only be set in seconds not millisecs , isnt there some other way? Does pcap_breakloop() stop immediately?

Comment: Try just starting another thread and use Sleep (Win) or nanosleep (*ux).